# Create a regex that will accept & but not +&+

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a string with regex. I need to get the first part before a clean `&`. A clean `&` does not have `+` right before or after it.

Clean &:

- 47&78
- a+bc&gsd+f

Not Clean &:

- fA+&71
- nap&+sys

For `Matisse+&+Sadko&sendtemp=1` the regex should return `Matisse+&+Sadko`.

I've tried to do it that way, but I it doesn't work:

```
.*(?!\+)&(?!\+).*
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(?!...)` is a (negative) lookahead expression, it checks whether the next characters do (not) match. So, you would need to add that one character to your regex, because the `&` is never a `+`:

```
(?!\+).&(?!\+)
```

But that would need at least one character before the `&`. Better use (negative) lookbehind:

```
(?<!\+)&(?!\+)
```

Read more on [Regex Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If your `&` is never at the string beginning or end, you could also just use a negated character class:

```
.*[^+]&[^+].*
```

...or, if it could, let that be optional:

```
^(?:.*[^+])?&(?:[^+].*)?$
```

Comment: That won't work if the input is `Matisse+&+Sadko&a=1&b=2`. In that case, `(.*[^+])&[^+]`'s group num. 1 will match `Matisse+&+Sadko&a=1`.

Comment: Sure, if you want to match the first occurence you would need to make the `.*` non-[greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) with `.*?`. I don't understand why you need them at all, but that depends on your application logic. If you want to match only the `&`, I recommend the second regex (lookaround).

Answer (score 1):

so, it is good, that you look at negative lookahead, but it task more(!) simple.
`[somesymbols]` - this is group of symbols, that regex accept.
`[^somesymbols]` - this is group of symbols, that regex doesn't accept.
so, just write this: `[^+]&[^+]` to filter your strings

Comment: This would fail to match a `&` at the start or end of the string.

Comment: let's show me example string in query (author try to parse query, am i right? how you think?)